# not getting desire output from recursion function

Tags: c, recursion, return-value, factorial, function-definition

When I use different approach to calculate factorial value from following method `n=n*i` then output I get in negative values

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
foo(int x)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
        x = x * i;
        printf("%d ", x);
    }

    return 0;

}

int
main()
{
    int x = 4, m;

    m = foo(x);
    printf(m);
    return 0;
}
```

Output I get:

```
4 8 24 96 480 2880 20160 161280 1451520 14515200 159667200 1916006400 -861720576 
Process finished.
```

I think updating in same value cause some problem
Pls help

Comment: Your `for` loop is changing the variable that is used to signify the end of the loop. It would therefore be an infinite loop, if it wasn't for the fact that an int will eventually wrap around and become negative. Also, I see no recursion here.

Comment: This is not recursion. Recursion is when foo() makes a call to itself, like `m = foo(x-1)`. Also, values above 12 will lead to an integer overflow (max positive int is 2147483647).

Comment: Didn't the compiler complain about `printf(m);`? In C, you can't dynamically convert integers like that.

Comment: In the function, `x` eventually overflowed and the behaviour was undefined, but somehow the ever-advancing `x` became apparently less than `i` (for all values of argument  `x > 1`).

Comment: @yacc The mathematical definition of the factorial function is recursive, even though programming-language-wise we can compute it recursively or iteratively.

Answer (score 3):

For starters your function is not recursive.:)

This call of `printf` in main

```
printf(m);
```

is incorrect. The first parameter of the function `printf` has the pointer type `const char * restrict`.

For the type `int` the maximum valid number for which factorial can be calculated is equal to `12`:

```
12! = 479001600
```

provided that `sizeof( int )` is equal to `4`.

It is better to use the return type of the function `unsigned long long int`. In this case the maximum valid number for which the factorial can be calculated is equal to `20`:

```
20! = 2432902008176640000
```

Also the function parameter should have at least the unsigned integer type `unsigned int`. There is no sense to declare the parameter as having a signed integer type.

And the return value `0` of the function does not make sense. The function should return the calculated factorial.

Also your function incorrectly calculates factorial for the value 0 that is a valid value. `0!` is equal to `1`.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
unsigned long long int foo( unsigned int n )
{
    unsigned long long int factorial = 1llu;

    while ( n > 1 ) factorial *= n--;

    return factorial;
}
```

If you want to write a recursive function then it can look the following way

```
unsigned long long int foo( unsigned int n )
{
    return n < 2 ? 1llu : n * foo( n - 1 ); 
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long int foo( unsigned int n )
{
    return n < 2 ? 1llu : n * foo( n - 1 );
}

int main( void )
{
    const unsigned int MAX_FACTORIAL_VALUE = 20;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= MAX_FACTORIAL_VALUE; i++)
    {
        printf( "%u! = %llu\n", i, foo( i ) );
    }
}
```

The program output will look like

```
0! = 1
1! = 1
2! = 2
3! = 6
4! = 24
5! = 120
6! = 720
7! = 5040
8! = 40320
9! = 362880
10! = 3628800
11! = 39916800
12! = 479001600
13! = 6227020800
14! = 87178291200
15! = 1307674368000
16! = 20922789888000
17! = 355687428096000
18! = 6402373705728000
19! = 121645100408832000
20! = 2432902008176640000
```

If you want then instead of the recursive function you can use the non-recursive function shown above.

You can also change the function such a way that it will signal the user that the passed value to the function is too big. A simple way is for example the following

```
unsigned long long int foo( unsigned int n )
{
    const unsigned int MAX_VALID_VALUE = 20;

    if (MAX_VALID_VALUE < n) return -1;

    unsigned long long int factorial = 1llu;

    while (n > 1) factorial *= n--;

    return factorial;
}
```

That is if the passed value is not in the acceptable range then the function returns the value `( unsigned long long int )-1`..

Then in main you can write

```
#include <limits.h>

//...

unsigned long long int m = foo( some_value );

if ( m == ULLONG_MAX ) puts( "Error: too big value." );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here. The main one is that your `for` loop is changing `x`, which is used to indicate when to stop the loop. You need to use a different variable to track your result. You would have an infinite loop if it wasn't for the fact than an `int` will eventually wrap around and become nagative.

Your loop uses `i < x` as the stop condition, but you need to include `x` in the equation. So it should be `i <= x`.

Also, your function returns 0, not the result of the factorial.

Lastly, you have:

```
printf(m);
```

This is not how `printf()` works, you need to give it a format string to tell it how to print the arguments, e.g.

```
printf("%d\n", m);
```

Putting all that together, you might have:

```
int factorial(int x)
{
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= x; i++) {
        result *= i;
        printf("%d ", result);
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 4, m;

    m = factorial(x);
    printf("%d\n", m);
    return 0;
}
```

Giving:

```
2 6 24 24
```

Comment: I do not see any recursion here. The question is: `not getting desire output from recursion function`

Comment: @0___________ The question is in the text, not the title. The title misstates the problem.

Comment: @0___________ I explained the problems with the code provided in the question. (And it was not me that gave you a DV, in case you wonder.)

Comment: @Barmar See my comment to user "yacc" above. (Factorial is *mathematically* recursive.) That said, one could still rightfully say that the title is misleading or (very) confusing.

Comment: @LoverofStructure "recursive" is a description of a particular algorithm. The mathematical definition is simply "product of integers from 1 to N", which is not mathematically recursive. Contrast it with Fibonacci, which is hard to describe in a non-recursive way.

Comment: @Barmar I think you are right. (Though in the end it's probably hard to draw a line since recursion is so deeply embedded in math -- even the Peano axiom's successor function is recursive.)

Answer (score -1):

1. In the recursive implementation you do not iterate in the loop
2. `printf` requires the format first

```
unsigned long long fact(unsigned int x) // as fact of the negative number is not defined
{
    if(x) return x * fact(x - 1);
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long m;
    unsigned int x = 5;

    m = fact(x);
    printf("%llu\n", m);
    return 0;
}
```

or checking if it does not overflow

```
unsigned long long fact(int x) // as fact of the negative number is not defined
{
    if(x) 
        if(x < 0 || x * (x - !x) < x ) return 0;
        else return x * fact(x - 1);
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long m;
    int x = 120;

    m = fact(x);
    if(m) printf("%llu\n", m);
    else printf("Undefined\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aby comment silent DV-ter?

Comment: Maybe cause you provided a solution but no explanation of the problem asked about? Especially since this is homework.

Comment: I was going to leave the compiler warning about mismatched types, until you used a negative argument. Please see [The factorials of negative integers have no defined meaning](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/927440/356452).

Comment: @WeatherVane indeed, corrected

Comment: Huh? You still compute a mathematically undefined value, and pass the wrong type. The additions to the original post are a complete mystery. If you want to embellish it, better to handle the notorious factorial overflow, and return 0.

Comment: @WeatherVane my first version was unsigned

Comment: I believe what's @Weather trying to point out is that you're passing an `unsigned long long int` to a function that expects an `int`.